# Group and subtracting data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario where each of my users buys two things from my shop, at different times.

```
+---------------------+----------+
| purchase_time       | user_id  |
+---------------------+----------|
| 2016-06-13 15:52:28 |   282725 |
| 2016-05-15 15:35:04 |   282725 |
| 2016-11-12 14:41:25 |   270307 |
| 2016-10-17 15:01:64 |   270307 |
| 2016-05-17 14:22:35 |   282085 |
| 2016-02-11 14:38:31 |   282085 |
+---------------------+----------+
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how long does it take (in terms of days/hours) between the initial purchase and the second purchase. I'm stumped on how to group each pair of purchases, do the subtraction, and then show it again on a per-user basis. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are always exactly two purchases, then just use `min()` and `max()`:

```
select user_id,
       timestampdiff(hour, min(purchase_time), max(purchase_time)) as diff_hours
from t
group by user_id;
```